# If Yamuna gave way to Lord Krishna, then why didn't the Ocean (Varuna) do the same for Rama?

Tags: krishna, ramayana, rama, rivers, varuna

If Yamuna gave way to Lord Krishna, then why didn't the Ocean (Varuna) do the same for Rama?

Two possible reasons I could think of are that

1. The Ocean affects the earth's wind cycle
2. Splitting the ocean for a narrow passage will release uncontrollable amounts of water and tsunamis, flooding many nations, whereas for rivers there might not be such devastating problems.

Is there an answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
      Aapaha Vs Aasura
```

Ocean is not Varuna. Varuna is one among Devaas. But, Samudra Raaja is cordial to both Devaas and Asuraas. Raavanaasura after getting boons from Great Lord Shiva is a respectable person to Samudra Raaja. Hence overpowering Raavanasura Samudra Raaja did not give way.

But, the corals of the ocean were the product of Agni and stars in space. They are on the side of Devaas. Hence the object of Devaas helped God Raama than the great kings who stood neutral between Devaas and Asuraas.

MODERN CONTEXT:
Fishes from oceans are proofs to above fact. They are called as ASURA fish from Indian ocean to Japanese coast.